# finding top two smallest value from a table

Tags: sql

How can I get either top 3 highest value as well as top 2 lowest value from a table?

Comment: Have u tried anything urself? 
Show us ur effort and explain what specifically did not work in ur code. As is, it appears that u r just asking us to do ur work for u.

Answer (score 2):

a quick google and you will get

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY value DESC LIMIT 3; //Highest

SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY value ASC LIMIT 2; //Lowest
```

next time google first.

[more on this link](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/select_limit.php)

Comment: You don't need to specify `ASC` explicitly since that's the default.

Comment: But LIMIT is not ANSI SQL, and no dbms specified in question. Which dbms is this for?

Comment: @jarlh, if no *DBMS* specified then default to `MySQL` ... LOL

Comment: @Rahul Thanks for the correction.

Comment: @Yokowasis, note that Rahul was joking... (No dbms specified implies ANSI SQL is assumed, not MySQL...)